# datetime.datetime object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python, pandas

I have small issues during my task:

Import defaultdict from collections and datetime from datetime.

Create a dictionary that defaults to a list called locations_by_month.

Loop over the crime_data list:

Convert the first element to a date object exactly like you did in the previous exercise.

If the year is 2016, set the key of locations_by_month to be the month of date and append the location (fifth element of row) to the values list.

Print the dictionary. This has been done for you!

```
# Import the pandas package
import pandas as pd

# Import data as DataFrame: df
 df = pd.read_csv('crime_sampler.csv')

# Create list of lists (rows)
crime_data = df.values.tolist()



# Import necessary modules
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

# Create a dictionary that defaults to a list: locations_by_month
locations_by_month = defaultdict(list)

# Loop over the crime_data list
for row in crime_data:
    # Convert the first element to a date object
    date = datetime.strptime(date[0], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

# If the year is 2016 
    if row.year == 2016:
    # Set the dictionary key to the month and add the location (fifth element) to the values list
    locations_by_month[row.month] = row[4]

# Print the dictionary
print(locations_by_month)
```

I get datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable error and i'm not sure that i'm doing everying right. I also pin screen of my csv file [CSVFILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3IDB.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). Please also ensure that the indentation in your code is *exactly* the same as the code in your editor.

Comment: ye, sorry, if statement is part of the loop

Answer (score 0):

I point out the error in the comment:

```py
for row in crime_data:
    date = datetime.strptime(date[0], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    #                        ^^^^ You may want row[0]
    #                        the `date` variable may defined before
    #                        and it's `datetime.datetime` object
    #                        thus you can't use `[]` accessor on it

    if row.year == 2016:
    #     ^^^^
       locations_by_month[row.month] = row[4]
    #                        ^^^^
    #                      row is list here, you shouldn't use `.` accessor
    #                      You could use `df.iterrows` instead,
    #                      but better way is use `pd.to_datetime` or something else.
```